# How to reference header icon images

Tags: image, magento, reference, header

I have a header used across all pages of my pages that use an image /images/shopIcon.png. I changed header.phtml to show this image with:

```
<img src="../images/shopIcon.png">
```

The image shows in the header on my homepage /example/catalog but will not show on any page deeper such as the cart page or product page.

Can someone please explain the correct way to put this image in the header? How should I reference it so it gets called on each page?

Notes:

I've tried:

```
<img src="/images/shopIcon.png">
```

Folder structure is as follows:

catalog/index.php <--Magento store

index.php <-- Main Page

images/shopIcon.png <--images folder

Comment: I ended up using this and moving the files into my skin/images folder. I don't like it as much because I now have to copies of the same picture but I guess it works... Alternate answers appreciated

    <?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/shopIcon.png'); ?>

Answer (score 0):

You should move the image to a theme's skin so you can use theme fallbacks.

However, as it currently stands

```
<?php echo $this->getUrl('') ?>images/shopIcon.png
```

should work.